# Cannot query the tobeprinted column on the transaction table

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I cannot understand why I cannot query the `tobeprinted` column on the transaction table when I can see it in the UI and return it in a search:

```sql
select tobeprinted, tranid FROM transaction where tranid = '1234567'
```

Results

```json
{
    "type": "https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.1",
    "title": "Bad Request",
    "status": 400,
    "o:errorDetails": [
        {
            "detail": "Invalid search query. Detailed unprocessed description follows. Search error occurred: Unknown identifier 'tobeprinted'. Available identifiers are: {transaction=transaction}.",
            "o:errorQueryParam": "q",
            "o:errorCode": "INVALID_PARAMETER"
        }
    ]
}
```